# Java Regex group matches spaces

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex and my output seems to be matching each single space but the capturing group is only alpha chars. I must be missing something.

```
String regexstring = new String("1234567                    Mike                     Peloso          ");

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]*");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(regexstring);

    while(matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(matcher.start()));
        String someNumberStr = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(someNumberStr);

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to extract all "words" (letter sequences)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no capturing group, but you need to use the `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (meaning `1` or more times). The `*` quantifier matches the preceding element **zero** or more times and [creates a disaster of output...](http://ideone.com/iddD4D)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]+");
```

And then print the match result:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start());
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/uakyjf)